# Get-InstalledModule Command Not Working Remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-5.1, powershell-module

There seems to be some issue with the PowerShell Command Get-InstalledModule.
E.g When I log in locally to a Windows server (PowerShell 5.1) and execute command **`Get-InstalledModule -Name Az`** it works fine but
when I remote into the same server using Enter-PSSession or New-PSSession and run the same command, it fails with the error can no convert null to a system.datetime
[image]

On Further troubleshooting, we found that this seems to be an issue with the PowerShell psmodule.psm1 file.

Somehow highlited command in the below screenshot is not working when called remotely.
[image]

Here are the lines in the psmodule.psm1 file which might be causing actual issue

[image]

has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
Get-Module -Name Az -ListAvailable
```

or to get all modules that isn't built-in

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | where RepositorySourceLocation
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs
Get-Module -Name Az -ListAvailable 
this command does not return any output, we need to run
Get-Module -Name Az.* -ListAvailable
which sometime may not help to indicate that Az module is completely intalled

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that the module isn't named `Az` or that you need to specify `Az*` to list `Az`?